# Anwendung und Synonyme von "Es geht Dich nichts an."

Tags: usage, synonym

Der Spruch

> "Es geht Dich (Sie) nichts an"

wird normalerweise ins Englische als

> "That's none of your business"

übersetzt.

Für mich ist jedoch nicht klar, wann genau man diesen Spruch verwenden darf, bzw. wann nicht. Gibt es höflichere Möglichkeit die selbe Idee auszudrücken?

Comment: Der für eine gute Übersetzung notwendige Kontext wird leider nicht mitgeliefert. Ein Möglichkeit ist *Das braucht Sie nicht zu kümmern*.

Answer (score 3):

Höflicher wäre es

> Das möchte ich für mich behalten.

zu sagen, oder etwa

> Das ist *meine* Angelegenheit.

da Ich-Botschaften generell als höflicher empfunden werden. Eine Begründung zu liefern die nicht zu viel verrät geht auch:

> Das ist meine Privatsache.
>
> Ich habe zugesagt, darüber Stillschweigen zu wahren.
>
> Bankgeheimnis.
>
> Geschäftsgeheimnis.
>
> Das wollen wir erst bekannt geben, wenn es so weit ist.

Je nach Situation kann es hilfreich sein, eine Teilinformation zu geben, die nicht so konkret ist, wie der andere gerne wünscht, aber ihm vielleicht doch weiterhilft:

> F: "Wann wird das denn fertig?"
>
> A: "Kann ich noch nicht sagen, aber noch in diesem Monat."

Was als höflich empfunden wird oder nicht, hängt aber auch immer sehr vom Tonfall und von der Beziehung ab, ist man kurz angebunden und presst die Antwort heraus oder wendet man sich dem Gesprächspartner zu, sieht ihn an, und wählt die Worte mit Bedacht ohne laut zu werden.

Comment: Du solltest den letzten Absatz fett machen oder sonstirgendwie hervorheben, denn er ist IMHO ein sehr wichtiger Bestandteil der Antwort. Der Gesamtkomplex von Mimik, Tonfall etc. ist nicht nur grundsätzlich ein integraler Bestandteil der Kommunikation, sondern eben auch gerade für die Frage höflich/unhöflich/beleidigend mindestens genauso wichtig wie die konkrete Wortwahl (was im Netz oft ein Grund für den Ausbruch von heftigem Streit ist, weil ohne diese Zusatzinformationen Scherze, vorsichtige Kritik oder flapsige Bemerkungen beim Empfänger viel schärfer ankommen als vom Urheber beabsichtigt

Comment: Danke, aber mir käme das etwas aufdringlich vor. Eigentlich weiß das ja jeder - man kann es nur beim theoretisieren leicht vergessen.

Answer (score 2):

> Für mich ist jedoch nicht klar, wenn genau man diesen Spruch verwenden darf, bzw. nicht darf. Gibt es höflichere Möglichkeit dieselbe Idee auszudrücken?

Diese Redewendung wird üblicherweise verwendet, wenn die Grenzen der *"Höflichkeit"* vom Gegenüber eventuell bereits überschritten sind, und unangemessene Fragen nach persönlichen Belangen gestellt wurden.

Man kann je nach dem auch sagen:

> Dazu werde ich keine Auskunft geben, das betrifft meinen höchstpersönlichen und privaten Bereich. Ich bitte um ihr Verständnis.<sup>1</sup>

Wenn es um juristische Belange geht, sollte man vielleicht eher folgende Antwort in Betracht ziehen:

> Ohne meinen Anwalt konsultiert zu haben, möchte ich von meinem Recht die Aussage zu verweigern Gebrauch machen.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Das ist extrem "höflich", und im Grunde gleichbedeutend mit "Noch eine weitere Frage dieser Art, und ich hau Dir in die Fresse!"</sub>

<sup>2)</sup><sub>Das ist die angemessene Antwort im Fall von Schwierigkeiten mit Fragen der Polizei/Staatsanwaltschaft/Justiz.</sub>

Comment: Natürlich kann man letzteres nur sagen, wenn man dann wirklich das Recht hat, also als Zeuge vor Gericht, unter bestimten Voraussetzungen. In allen anderen Situationen kann man einfach sagen: "Dazu möchte ich nichts sagen, tut mir Leid".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - Das sehe ich anders. Man kann durchaus, wenn man das Gefühl hat, der Gesprächspartner stellt eine unangemessen persönliche Frage, die in diesem Kontext absurde Formulierung mit Anwalt und Aussageverweigerung verwenden, um damit etwas in der Art auszudrücken "was bringt Dich auf die abwegige Idee, Du hättest einen Anspruch darauf, das zu erfahren?"

Comment: @Volker: Man kann natürlich so manches sagen, aber es macht nicht immer Sinn. <g> Man könnte es scherzhaft sagen, aber sogar in dem Fall finde ich es weniger gelungen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ich bin bei Volker: "Ohne meinen Anwalt sage ich da nichts" ist durchaus auch eine humoristisch unter Freunden verwendbare Version von "no comment"